# I can't performance profile my game?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0

It seems that I can't performance-profile my XNA 4.0 game on Windows. Whenever I start the performance profiler, I get the following issue:

"Could not launch . Injection of runtime library failed."

What is that supposed to mean? I'm on X64 by the way, and the file is compiled as X86, which is required by XNA.

Profiling is important to me.

I'm on the reach XNA 4.0 profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the ANTS Performance Profiler.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you're on x64 - since the XNA you're running is x86 it will hook the x86 CLR and so you have to run the x86 profiler.

Comment: The folder you launched the profiler EXE file from (the one that opens the black window in the background) is labelled "64" - go up one level to the "32" folder and start that profiler, then use it to start your XNA project.

Comment: Where, more specifically, is this file located?

Comment: Download the CLR profiler for the target framework - for example, if your app is for the .Net 4.0 runtime, download the 4.0 profiler (this link for 4.0: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273 ) Once you've downloaded the right one, run it and it will ask you for a location to unzip the files. Choose a location you can access - like your desktop. After you have unzipped it, go to where you unzipped it and there will be two folders inside - a "32" and a "64". Try the EXE inside each folder - if one doesn't work, the other will.

Comment: I'm trying to use the inbuilt profiler in Visual Studio 2010. Not the CLR profiler. Can you redefine the answer?